# How can i update M2E ebay inventory using Magento 2 API

Tags: php, magento2.2, m2e-pro

I have created a tool in Python using Magento 2 API which update magento inventory and price through api.

Magento Website have a M2E Pro Extension ( https://marketplace.magento.com/m2e-ebay-amazon-magento2.html )
 which is used to sale on ebay.

M2e Pro is developed to detect all changes made via Standard Magento interface and Standard Magento models automatically.

If you are using any external tool or API to update your Magento catalog - M2E Pro may not be aware of these changes.

In this case, we always advise our customers to use Programmatic Possibilities to work with the extension.

Please find details here:

https://docs.m2epro.com/display/BestPractice/Programmatic+Possibilities+to+work+with+Extension

and

https://docs.m2epro.com/display/BestPracticeMagento2/Suitable+Articles+from+the+Best+Practice+for+Magento+v1.x#SuitableArticlesfromtheBestPracticeforMagentov1.x-ProgrammaticPossibilitiestoworkwithExtension

Can anyone help me out how i can implement these changes in website.

All i want to update M2E using magento API

Where to add new methods and what would be Magento 2 API End Point for M2E pro